# Creality Ender 5 S1, I can move z axis downwards but not upwards, Why?

Tags: z-axis, creality-ender-5, creality

I bought a Ender 5 S1, 3d printer (without limit switch version), I could be able to asemble it. Every axis works fine, however I cannot make the printing platform move upwards from the GUI.

I can make Y axis and X axis move without any problem.But Z axis moves only down, not up.

I tried to fix it by installing the latest firmware 1.0.7, but it didn't worked.What can I do to debug or fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, My wide CRTOUCH power cable was loose. I am a begginer so I didn't reliazed that loose CRtouch Power cable was the problem

When CRTouch is loose, you cannot move the Z axis probably because of security issues.